# Postgres - Dealing with empty set of elements

Tags: postgresql, multivalue

Let's consider that I have a table that has a multivaluated column of type json that holds arrays. So in order to normalize the relation one could do:

```
   select 
    id,  
    description,
    json_array_elements(letters)
  from
  (
    values
    (1, 'good', '["a","b", "c"]'::json),
    (2, 'bad', '[]'::json)
  ) as aTable(id,description,letters);
```

(Ready-to-run example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/b9U6EmRh))

The thing here is that the row with id 2 is NOT listed as the array is empty (or null).

So I do wonder what kind of thing I have to do in order to get that row with a mock|default|hardcoded value... for example I have try this:

```
  select 
    id,  
    description,
      CASE 
        WHEN json_array_length(letters) = 0 THEN '"x"'::json
        ELSE json_array_elements(letters)
      END 
  from
  (
    values
    (1, 'good', '["a","b", "c"]'::json),
    (2, 'bad', '[]'::json)
  ) as aTable(id,description,letters)
```

(RTR example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZFT1jm5Y))

And postgres states that is not possible as

```
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
LINE 6:         ELSE json_array_elements(letters)
                     ^
HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.
```

I have tried the HINT but also has no results...

```
   select 
    id, 
    description, 
    l.letter
  from
  (
    values
    (1, 'good', '["a","b", "c"]'::json),
    (2, 'bad', '[]'::json)
  ) as aTable(id,description,letters)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN json_array_length(letters) = 0 THEN '"x"'::json
            ELSE json_array_elements(letters)
        END
  ) as l(letter)
```

So problably I'm not getting the HINT...

I do wonder if someone can help me with this.

Thanks

Víctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to substitute a json array of "x":

```
select 
    id,  
    description,
    json_array_elements(CASE WHEN json_array_length(letters) = 0 THEN '["x"]'::json ELSE letters END)
from
  (
    values
    (1, 'good', '["a","b", "c"]'::json),
    (2, 'bad', '[]'::json)
  ) as aTable(id,description,letters);
```

Comment: This answer is most simple for me, as I didn't realize that I can work on the json_array_elements's argument! It is very clever... thanks. The other answer is actually more complete but I mark this as correct as it appears first (I resort to time criteria to resolve this dilema, it is a shame that SO doens't admit multiple correct answers as in life this is a very common case)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `left join` with a condition `on true`

```
with cte(id,description,letters) as (
  values
    (1, 'good', '["a","b", "c"]'::json),
    (2, 'bad', '[]'::json)
)
select id,description, COALESCE(l.value::text, 'x') as letter
from cte
left join json_array_elements_text(letters) l on true
```

Its also can be done using :

```
with cte(id,description,letters) as (
  values
    (1, 'good', '["a","b", "c"]'::json),
    (2, 'bad', '[]'::json)
)
select id,description, COALESCE(l.value::text, 'x') as letter
from cte,
json_array_elements_text(case when letters::text = '[]' then '[null]'::json else letters end) l;
```

`json_array_elements_text('[null]')` returns null,

`json_array_elements_text('[]')` does not return anything

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OI1cFO7F)

Comment: Thanks you give me a lot of insight along with some proper solutions. Thanks again. Sadly I had to mark one correct answer and as both answer are correct (for me) I just take the one that appears first. I would mark this as correct too if SO allow me to do that.

Comment: ```select *
from (
  values
    (1, 'good', '["a","b", "c"]'::json),
    (2, 'bad', '[]'::json)
) as cte(id,description,letters) 
left join json_array_elements_text(letters) l on true``` <= it just the same solution but using "literal tables" instead of common table expressions

Comment: Its Ok .. Glad to hear we could help you :)